# Working with picture in AlternateContent tag

Tags: python, image, lxml, openxml, python-docx

I need to move an element from one document to another by using `python-docx`. The element is `AlternateContent` which represents shapes and figures in *Office Word*, the issue here is that one of the elements contains an image like this:

```
<AlternateContent>
    <Choice Requires="wpc">
        <drawing>
            <inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="0DCE320C" wp14:editId="0DCE320D">
                <extent cx="5826587" cy="2494357" />
                <effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="1270" />
                <docPr id="1108" name="Zeichenbereich 5" />
                <cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1" />
                </cNvGraphicFramePr>
                <graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                    <graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas">
                        <wpc>
                            <pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                                <nvPicPr>
                                    <cNvPr id="687" name="Picture 28" />
                                    <cNvPicPr>
                                        <picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1" />
                                    </cNvPicPr>
                                </nvPicPr>
                                <blipFill>
                                    <blip r:embed="rId20">
                                        <extLst>
                                            <ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                                <useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0" />
                                            </ext>
                                        </extLst>
                                    </blip>
                                    <srcRect />
                                    <stretch>
                                        <fillRect />
                                    </stretch>
                                </blipFill>
                            </pic>
                        </wpc>
                    </graphicData>
                </graphic>
            </inline>
        </drawing>
    </Choice>
</AlternateContent>
```

What I did is extract the image by getting its `rid` from `r:embed` and then save it to the disk, after I re-add the image using `add_picture()` from the `Run` class, sadly this process cannot be achieved because from above example the `<pic>` tag is not included in a `run`.
So my question is how I can save the element `AlternateContent` into python object then re-add it to a Word document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the fact that this functionality is not fully supported through `python-docx` API and processing images is kind of complicated -because of the multiple parts that must be handled (ImagePart, Relationship, rId)- the work had to be done at a low level by going into `lxml`, in these steps:

- Save the images into the disk when reading the file.
- Get `rid` of the image to add it separately.
- Build a `pic:pic` element using `lxml` functions (`SubElement` and `Element`)
- Repeat the process to handle all the pictures.

```py
for image_elem in list_of_images:
       image_path = image_elem("image_path")
       rel_id, _ = _run.part.get_or_add_image(image_path)
       image_name = image_path.split("\\")[-1]
       add_image_to_shape(shape_element, rel_id, image_name)
```

The function `add_image_to_shape` is done like this:

```py
shape = [elem for elem in shape_element.iterdescendants(tag='{http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas}wpc')][0]
    image = etree.SubElement(shape, 'pic')
    nvPicPr = etree.SubElement(image, 'nvPicPr')
    cNvPr = etree.SubElement(nvPicPr, 'cNvPr')
    cNvPr.set('id', '1')
    cNvPr.set('descr', image_name)
    cNvPicPr = etree.SubElement(nvPicPr, 'cNvPicPr')
    picLocks = etree.SubElement(cNvPicPr, 'picLocks')
    picLocks.set('noChangeAspect', '1')
    picLocks.set('noChangeArrowheads', '1')
    blipFill = etree.SubElement(image, 'blipFill')
    blip = etree.SubElement(blipFill, 'blip')
    blip.set('embed', rel_id)
    srcRect = etree.SubElement(blipFill, 'srcRect')
    stretch = etree.SubElement(blipFill, 'stretch')
    fillRect = etree.SubElement(stretch, 'fillRect')
```